# Firestore security rules in to prevent sensitive field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-security

I am modeling a database with Firestore, for a small company.

I have a collection of departments. Each department is a document.
In the company, there will never be more than 50 employees. I would like to keep each employee as a map.

so a department document will be like this;

```
{ 
  emp1: { name: 'tom', age:23, email: 'tom@x.com'},
  emp2: { name: 'mike', age:35, email: 'mike@x.com'}
}
```

I would like to keep the age field private, it should be accessed only by superusers. From what I learnt, it is not possible to put access level at the granularity of a field. When a client receives the document, he will have access to all fields.

How can I go about that, I should keep a sub-collection of ages, would that work? Coming from SQL, and already done this smoothly in SQL, I cannot get my head around to have a collection just for a single integer.

Or is there any other alternative? I do not want to have a collection of employees.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609770/firestore-restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules/46614729#46614729

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have data associated with one entity (a user) that should have varying permissions for different fields of that data, it will be easiest if you split those fields into documents in different subcollections organized under that entity.  The security rules will be much easier to implement in that case.  The case of simple public/private data:

```
users/{uid}/public
  - data
    - name
    - email
users/{uid}/private
  - data
    - age
```

Then your rules target each subcollection separately:

```
match /users/{uid}/public {
  allow read: true;
}

match /users/{uid}/private {
  allow read: if  **...whatever conditions you choose, if any...**
}
```

Comment: thanks, there is a many to many relationship between departments and users, how I can go about that? In each department document, I keep a foreign key to the these users as an array?

Comment: Please edit the question to more accurately describe the problem with many to many relationships that isn't satisfied by this answer.

Comment: actually that was a follow up question.

Comment: I don't fully understand it - please post a new question describing the issue.